# get embed url links from youtube channelwith xml in xcode

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, youtube, google-api

I have been trying to embed a list of videos from certain YouTube channel in my table view. I learned how to embed each on manually with a list of urlStrings. Now I would like to upgrade it into a more robust process by retrieving the links from YouTube by itself. The question:

How do I get the url(s) of each videos from the channel using xml?
-I know "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channels?q=myChannel" returns something I want, I just dont know how to go from there to a list of these "http://www.youtube.com/embed/FmtA2Tq062o".

Thanks in advance!